# How to properly create hist in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I want to plot a histogram with three columns with heights `5`, `10` and `20`. Each column will have a width of 1. So the first column will have height `5` on the interval `[0,1]`, the second one `10` on the interval `[1,2]` and so on.

```
plt.hist([5, 10, 20], bins=range(0,4,1))
plt.show()
```

But as result I have nothing:
[image]

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hist` computes the number of data samples that lies within a given bin and then displays the resulting frequencies as a bar plot. You don't actually need `hist` because you already *have* the frequencies. You simply need [`bar`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.bar) to display these frequencies as a bar plot. The first input specifies the left edge location of each bar and then we can use the `width` kwarg to specify the width of each bar.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.bar([0, 1, 2], [5, 10, 20], width=1)
```

[image]

Comment: could you at the question once again, please? I've updated it.

Comment: @RomaKarageorgievich Updated.